# Check for time coverage for each specific type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

Suppose I have the following data tables in SQL :

```
  **TimeRange**

  StartTime   -   EndTime   -   Type
  ----------------------------------
  00:00       -   01:45     -   A
  01:50       -   03:30     -   A
  03:35       -   03:40     -   A
  03:45       -   13:15     -   A
  13:20       -   19:25     -   A
  19:30       -   23:55     -   A

  00:00       -   02:50     -   B
  03:30       -   12:30     -   B
  12:35       -   13:40     -   B
  13:45       -   18:15     -   B
  18:20       -   19:25     -   B
  21:00       -   23:55     -   B

  00:00       -   11:55     -   C

  **Type**

  TypeID  -   Name 
  ----------------
  1       -   A 
  2       -   B
  3       -   C
```

Each type from **Type**  table should cover time range 00:00 - 23:55. Each StartTime = previous EndTime + 5. We should select the rows that doesn't have coverage. In the mentioned example the following should be selected out :

```
 Output:
 StartTime  EndTime Type
 ------------------------
 02:55      03:25    B
 19:30      20:55    B
 12:00      23:55    C
```

Can you please help me in writing corresponding query for this purpose?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Add the code which you had

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have the draft version yet. I'm trying to write set-based query with out using cursors, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later you can use Lag:

***Setup***

```
CREATE TABLE #TimeRange
(
 StartTime Time,
 EndTime   Time,
 [Type]     CHAR(1)
 )

 INSERT INTO #TimeRange
 VALUES
    ('00:00','01:45','A'),
    ('01:50','03:30','A'),
    ('03:35','03:40','A'),
    ('03:45','13:15','A'),
    ('13:20','19:25','A'),
    ('19:30','23:55','A'),
    ('00:00','02:50','B'),
    ('03:30','12:30','B'),
    ('12:35','13:40','B'),
    ('13:45','18:15','B'),
    ('18:20','19:25','B'),
    ('21:00','23:55','B'),
    ('00:00','11:55','C')
```

**Edit Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #Type
(
    TypeId INT,
    Name    CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #Type
Values (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3,'C'), (4,'D')
```

***Query***

```
;WITH CTEPrevEndTime
AS
(
    -- This finds the Previous End Time for each row for the same Type
    SELECT [Type], 
            StartTime, 
            EndTime, 
            COALESCE(
                DATEADD(mi, 5, 
                    LAG(EndTime) OVER (Partition By [Type] ORDER BY StartTime )
                ), StartTime) As PrevEndTime
    FROM #TimeRange
)

-- Find the records with gaps
    SELECT [Type], PrevEndTime As StartTime, DATEADD(mi, -5, StartTime) As EndTime
    FROM CTEPrevEndTime
    WHERE PrevEndTime <> StartTime
UNION
-- find the [Type] that doesn't start at 00:00:00
    SELECT [Type], CAST('00:00' AS Time) As StartTime, DateAdd(mi, -5, Min(StartTime)) As EndTime
    FROM #TimeRange
    GROUP BY [Type]
    HAVING Min(StartTime) > '00:05'
UNION
-- find the [Type] that doesn't End at 23:55:00
    SELECT [Type], DATEADD(mi, 5,Max(EndTime)) AS StartTime, CAST('23:55' AS TIME) As EndTime
    FROM #TimeRange
    GROUP BY [Type]
    HAVING Max(EndTime) < '23:50'
UNION
--Edit
-- Find Types with no TimeRange
SELECT T1.Name As [Type], CAST('00:00' AS Time) As StartTime, CAST('23:55' AS TIME) As EndTime
FROM #Type T1
WHERE Not Exists (SELECT * FROM #TimeRange T2 WHERE  T1.Name = T2.Type)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How can we check for all types from Type table, if they cover time ranges or not. For example, there could be another type 'D' in Type table that doesn't participate in TimeRange at all. In such case we should report 00:00 - 23:55 - 'D'